# The Running Time Calculation

Tags: java, runtime

I have a question about the running time calculation of a for loops.

This is an example illustrated in "2.4.1 A Simple Example" from the book Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java. The author is Mark Allen Weiss. This is page 36.

The books says "Line 2 has the hidden costs of initializing i, testing i ≤ N, and incrementing i. The total cost of all these is 1 to initialize, N+1 for all the tests, and N for all the increments, which is 2N + 2." Line 2 is `for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )`. I am wondering the reason why is code N+1 for all the tests i ≤ N. I feel like it should be N, because it costs N times to test if i ≤ N. I must be wrong, but I am wondering why.

```
public static int sum( int n )
{
    int partialSum;
    partialSum = 0;
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        partialSum += i * i * i;
    return partialSum;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: if n is `1`, then first iteration will init (1), compare (1), execute loop body (1), increment (1) and then again will compare (2nd) to check whether it should stop looping, this is why there is always 1 additional comparison

Comment: well we usually start with i=0 and since the first time you run the loop is zero once you reach n you are at n-1 because n is an integer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I think I understand now. After the iteration of i = n, i will be assigned as n + 1. For the next iteration, n+1 <= n is false, so the loops stops, this is where the extra 1 comes in. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the loop only runs N times, but remember i is incremented and checked every loop. So once the loop has run N times, it has to do the check 1 more time to see if it needs to run the loop again.